# Compiling an angular html (owl carousel) without using $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, owl-carousel-2

Currently i am having trouble compiling an appended html to my scope.

The owl carousel **works perfectly fine** but

The angular method **ng-click** doesn't work anymore.

my issue here is how to inject my appended html into the app correctly.

```
CategoryCarouselDirective.$inject = ['$filter', '$compile'];

function CategoryCarouselDirective($filter, $compile) {

    return {
        scope: {
            categoryCarousel: '&'
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            function createCarousel() {

                var data = scope.categoryCarousel() , rawHtml = '', compileHtml;

                angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) {
                    rawHtml += '<li class="item">'
                    rawHtml += '      <i role="image"></i>'
                    rawHtml += '      <h1>' + value.Category + '</h1>'
                    rawHtml += '      <p>' + value.CategoryDesc + '</text></p>'
                    rawHtml += '      <a href="javascript:(0);" ng-click="myCtrl.GetAllArticleByCategoryId(' + value.CategoryId + ')">View all <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>'
                    rawHtml += '</li>'
                });

                $(elem).append(rawHtml);
                $compile(elem.contents())(scope);

                if (data != null) {

                    $(elem).owlCarousel({
                        items: 4,
                        slideBy: 1,
                        stopOnHover: true,
                        autoplay: true,
                        autoplayTimeout: 2000,
                        autoplayHoverPause: true,
                        rewind: true,
                        responsive: true,
                        slideSpeed: 2000,
                        paginationSpeed: 2000
                    });

                    $(".next").on('click', function () {
                        owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
                    })
                    $(".prev").on('click', function () {
                        owl.trigger('prev.owl.carousel');
                    })
                }
            }
        },
    };
}
```

here is my html page

```html
<div class="container-fluid unopedia-container" ng-init="myCtrl.Initialize()">


                <header class="row">
                    <nav class="customNavigation">
                        <a class="btn prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    </nav>

                    <ul id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme" category-carousel="myCtrl.GetCategoryCarousel()"></ul>

                </header>
</div>
```